# TFS 2017 Upgrade SQL Server Always on

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2014, alwayson

When upgrading TFS 2015.1 to TFS 2017.2 do I leave SQL Server 2014 Always On turned on? We have TFS 2015.1 running on SQL Server 2014 with Always on and everything is working fine. Upgrading to TFS 2017.2 and assume I just leave the database server as is. Can I upgrade TFS with Always on running?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave TFS pointed at the AG, you need to make sure you have enough space for potential log file growth because the database will be left in FULL recovery mode. TFS does warn you about this during the upgrade.

If you disable the AG and point TFS at a single node, it will upgrade in Simple recovery mode, and you will need to resetup the AG after the upgrade.

Depending on how big your TFS Collection databases are and the amount of free space you have for your logs (and maybe the data files too) depends which you need.

Comment: +1 - we've generally split the AG for larger upgrades so we have an easy rollback option if there's ever an issue.

Comment: When you say enough space for the log file to grow, which one? And how much might it  grow? Which log file will blow up? Tempdb? defaultCollection.log? I think we have plenty of space. Our Default Collection is about 250gb and we have about 1.2 TB free.

Comment: The log files on SQL server are usually the .ldf files. If you have 2-3 times the size of you collection db(mdf files) free, you should be fine. To know for sure, the only way is to test and see if 1.2TB free is enough. Running out of log space on a production system isn't desirable.